# Align checkboxes horizontally

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to have the mat-checkboxes here float horizontally in an organized way.
Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container" style="float:left;padding:0px;">
    <ul *ngFor="let title of addonTitles" style="clear:both">
        <li style="padding:0px">
            <b>{{ title }}</b>
        </li>
        <div class="container" >
            <ul *ngFor="let addon of bs.addons" style="padding:0px;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                <section *ngIf="addon.category === title" let i = index style="float:left;min-width: 125px;">
                    <mat-checkbox (change)="selectAddon($event)" [value]="addon.cbsCode">{{ addon.cbsCode }}</mat-checkbox>
                </section>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is how I have it now:

[image]

Comment: You could set a `min-width` CSS value on the `<section>` elements

Comment: Thanks @SeanDenny. It came out the way I wanted it, but how do i utilize the extra white space on the right, that means have them spread horizontally.

Comment: Having the inner `.container` have a `display: inline-block` may work

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: Under UL without any LI is not valid markup anyhow.

Comment: @Hanif, I have changed the h6 to li now, please check above code. But still it doesn't show up the way i wanted it.

Comment: Put the `display: inline-block` on the <ul> (btw you can use a simple <div> here), not the container.

Comment: Also I recommend to stop using inline-styles. use class-selectors and assign styles to them in your component's .css or .scss files

Comment: Thanks @Phil. display: inline-block didn't work out either. I would definitely move all the styles to a CSS after I get this working the way I wanted it.

Comment: @Sumchans Does container have a width: 100% ? If it has, then something is wrong, because inline-block should work. In this case please inspect/debug the relevant elements (container and ul) in your browser and post their applied css styles

Comment: @Phil, yes the container width was not at 100% width, changed it, but still the same way.